# Global variable defined in file cannot be changed

Tags: python

If I run a `.py` file that contains

```
a = 42

def foo(num):
    global a
    a = num
```

Then typing `foo(12)` into the interactive console does absolutely nothing.

```
>>> foo(12)
>>> a
42
```

Only if I type that block into the console does it actually work.

```
>>> foo(12)
>>> a
12
```

Why is this?

Comment: What is num exactly? And you don't return a's value, what do you expect?

Comment: @Inkblot I added some extra info

Comment: Could `a` live in a foo.py file loaded with `import`? If yes, please say exactly how you import everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are changing the variable `a` on the module level.
I assume you simply imported everything from that module.

Let the file `mymodule.py` contain the code

```
 a = 42

 def foo(num):
     global a
     a = num
```

Now let's run an interpreter session:

```
>>> from mymodule import *
>>> a
42
>>> foo(12)
>>> a
42
>>> import mymodule
>>> mymodule.a
12
```

Comment: Nice catch! Was still trying to guess what could have been done... Anyway, `from module import *` is generally source of problems because except on carefuly designed modules, it breaks into pieces the modularization.

Comment: I was using the `%run` magic command. It seems that's similar to `from ... import *`